# Which database to use when you have a 6 billion of rows inside and need to query rows with from list of IDs?

Tags: database-design, nosql, database-recommendation, elasticsearch

We are currently researching our case of storing the road distances between cities. Right now we have 6 billion of those distances.

Our structure right now in SQL Server is that we have a `float` which represents the relationship between cities.  For example if we have a city with `Id` 1 inside the `Locations` table and a city with `Id` 2 inside the same table, a row with distance from 1 to 2 will look like `1.2,'1000 miles'`. That column is indexed.

So to get the distance from the city `1000` to the city `2535`, we would find `1000.2535` inside the `Distances`.

Besides getting single distances, we need to select groups of 1000 distances from those 6 billion rows:

```
SELECT
  id
 ,distance
FROM
  Distances 
WHERE 
  id IN (1000.2535, 1.2, ...)
```

Right now we've only tested SQL Server on a local machine and it gives us around 300 ms for such query of 1000 rows, but only when we set a 50 ms timeout (this is needed for a lot of parallel requests from multiple users), if 50 ms timeout is not used it just grows exponentially like 300 ms for the first, 500 ms for the second, 800 ms for the third, etc.

And right now we taking a look at ElasticSearch specifically for `mget`.

So my questions are:

1. Which database would you recommend for such a use case?
2. What would you recommend besides what we've thought of maybe some other ideas like splitting into two different columns cities IDs, etc?
3. What would be the best ways to optimize such a database?

Comment: I would rethink using a float as key for two cities. Truncation and rounding error are going to cause problems. As @bbaird pointed out a composite key is a much better solution. If you really want to use a numeric identifier, I recommend a packed bit wise representation--that may limit your options on databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My assumption here is using `FLOAT` in place of the actual composite key is slowing the query engine's ability to create the proper estimates.

So instead of using the "clever" column, just use a composite primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE Country
(
  CountryCd  CHAR(3)      NOT NULL  --ISO Country Code
 ,Name       VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Country PRIMARY KEY (CountryCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT AK_Country UNIQUE (Name)
)
;
CREATE TABLE Subdivision  --State/province/region/county etc.
(
  CountryCd      CHAR(3)      NOT NULL
 ,SubdivisionCd  CHAR(3)      NOT NULL  --ISO subdivision code
 ,Name           VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_Subdivision_Division_Of_Country FOREIGN KEY (CountryCd) REFERENCES Country (CountryCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Subdivision PRIMARY KEY (CountryCd, SubdivisionCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT AK_Subdivision UNIQUE (CountryCd, Name)
)
;
CREATE TABLE City
(
  CityId         INT          NOT NULL
 ,CountryCd      CHAR(3)      NOT NULL
 ,SubdivisionCd  CHAR(3)      NOT NULL
 ,Name           VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_City_Located_In_Subdivision FOREIGN KEY (CountryCd, SubdivisionCd) REFERENCES Subdivision (CountryCd, SubdivisionCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_City PRIMARY KEY (CityId)
 ,CONSTRAINT AK_City UNIQUE (CountryCd, SubdivisionCd, Name)
)
;
CREATE TABLE CityRoadDistance
(
  SourceCityId       INT  NOT NULL
 ,DestinationCityId  INT  NOT NULL
 ,RoadDistance       INT  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_CityDistance_From_City FOREIGN KEY (SourceCityId) REFERENCES City (CityId)
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_CityDistance_To_City FOREIGN KEY (DestinationCityId) REFERENCES City (CityId)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_CityDistance PRIMARY KEY (SourceCityId, DestinationCityId)
 ,CONSTRAINT CK_CityDistance_SourceCityId_LT_DestinationCityId CHECK (SourceCityId < DestinationCityId) --Enforces only one record per city pair
)
;
```

Easy enough to find the single distance:

```
SELECT
  RoadDistance
FROM
  CityDistance
WHERE
  SourceCityId = 7 
    AND DestinationCityId = 235
```

But as you said the secondary requirement is to return 1,000 in less than 50 ms.
You won't be able to use `IN`, so you will need to build a list for the `WHERE` clause (e.g. `(SourceCityId = 7 AND DestinationCityId = 235) OR (SourceCityId = 1345 AND DestinationCityId = 2934)`...).

This should allow the query engine to look at things and say: "Oh, I only need to perform 1,000 seeks" and return your data relatively quickly.  However for 50 ms or less you're going to need some *very fast* SSDs or the pages already cached in memory.

Alternatives would be something like an in-memory key-value store.  This would cut down on compilation and seek time somewhat, but I'd try using an actual composite key and seeing what happens.

Comment: 1. There will be only 7 -> 235 because we generate a distance matrix and basically it will be the same
2. Both will not exist at all only one entry for both lanes we will always take lowest ID as a Source City
3. We will not add new cities at all if we want to we will just regenerate distance matrices and put it back inside database, so there will be no insertions at all only query
4. STDistance is not our case because we need a road distance which we will take out from OpenStreetMap + OSRM

Comment: Right now we actually use STDistance to calculate distances by air miles and we store them in-memory tables. It works fine, but road distances is kinda hard to get via SQL Server and even integrate it. The only way I remember is that we would need to switch to Postgres and use PostGIS + pgRouting, and it's kinda slow anyway, so storing all road distances in a static table without any interference is the best way for us.

Comment: @ArtemBiryukov That type of information would have been helpful in your original quesiton.

Comment: maybe we will need to have 7 -> 235 and 235 -> 7 rows, but this will bloat our table size, so probably we will just generate a `WHERE` query based on the knowledge that the SourceCityID will always be less than DestinationCityID. And we don't have to have a relations too because we know city IDs beforehand and we don't have to join anything together just get the distance numbers and then glue it with another database in the same order because we don't really like the idea of having everything inside one database like our business data and distances data it might slow everything.

Answer (score 2):

SQL is a relationnal database. If you want this to perform well in SQL, you will have to review the design so that it is normalized.
Otherwise, SQL will have to read all row in order to find the "id"s which will not perform well.

If you had a table with "From", "to" and "distance" that contains the ID of the first city, id of the second city and the distance, then indexes would be usable to seek into the right records and you would get great performance from SQL.

P.s. Using a float type to store "relation" is not a great way to do stuff in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the response we will research it with two columns and I'll share the performance.

Comment: once you are done and you are running your queries, look at the execution plan to make sure it is not doing a full table scan. If it does, you will have to look at your queries and indexes to make sure they are ok